# Is there is any way to replace the default search module in Drupal

Tags: drupal

i am planning to create an custom search module in drupal .my aim is to replace the existing search feature (ie the default search ) is there is any way to override the default search feature ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [hook_search](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_search/6) and create your own search, and you can use [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) to set your default search and/or disable the standard ones.

You can also just use the [Forms API](http://drupal.org/node/204270) and [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) and do something completely custom.

Also check out the accepted answer to [Search hook for filtering results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426366/search-hook-for-filtering-results) for another idea.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is! See this example: http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of your Drupal background - but if you're new, you might like to know: you can do a lot with Exposed Filters in Views to provide search functionalitites.  Depending on what you want to do, you could just de-activate the search module, and create a View with exposed filters for searching the appropriate content types and fields, and create a Block display for that view (on the left side of the UI, where you make a "page").